# STORYBLOK, RUBY: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll, storyblok

I don't know that much about **RUBY**, just thought that you guys might help me with this. I'm using Storyblok as my headless CMS and JEKYLL when I'm building serve it this is the error that I got;

```
33: from C:/project/test/_plugins/storyblok_generator.rb:8:in `generate'
32: from C:/project/test/_plugins/storyblok_cms/generator.rb:12:in `generate!'
C:/project/test/vendor/cache/ruby/2.7.0/gems/storyblok-3.0.1/lib/storyblok/client.rb:354:in `block (2 levels) in find_and_fill_links': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

the code below is from **_plugins/storyblok_cms/generator.rb**

```
def generate!
  timestamp = Time.now.to_i
  links = client.links(cv: timestamp)['data']['links']
  stories = client.stories(per_page: 100, page: 1, cv: timestamp)['data']['stories']   #line 12

  stories.each do |story|
    # create all pages except global (header,footer,etc.)
    content_type = story['content']['component']
    if content_type != 'shared'
      site.pages << create_page(site, story, links)
    end
    rescue UnknownContentTypeError => e
    # for production, raise unknown content type error;
    # for preview and other environments, issue an warning only since the content_type might be available
    # but the code handling that content type might be in a different branch.
    Jekyll.env == 'production' ? raise :  Jekyll.logger.warn(e.message)
  end

  site.data['stories'] = stories
  site.data['articles'] = stories.select { |story| story['full_slug'].start_with?('articles') }
  site.data['shared'] = stories.select { |story| story['full_slug'].start_with?('shared') }
end
```

the code below is from **_plugins/storyblok_generator.rb**

```
require "storyblok"

module Jekyll
  class StoryblokGenerator < Jekyll::Generator
    safe true

    def generate(site)
      StoryblokCms::Generator.new(site).generate!   #line 8
    end
  end
end
```

Additional Info:

- **ruby version:** ruby 2.7.4p191 (2021-07-07 revision a21a3b7d23) [x64-mingw32]
- **jekyll version:** jekyll 4.2.1
- **OS**: Windows 10

Comment: Which line is line 8 in `storyblok_generator.rb`?

Comment: When `content_type = story['content']['component']` is line 8 in `storyblok_generator.rb` then the error tells you that one of the `stories` is `nil` or that there is a `story` that has a `content` that is `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found the solution to this, So this error occurs because I have created a page template in Block Library in Storyblok and then firing `bundle exec jekyll serve` command in terminal without creating the page template source/file in my project directory.

So I have an `about_us` block (content-type) in Block Library created and then when I fire `bundle exec jekyll serve` without creating an `about_us.html` first in `_layouts` folder, It would trigger the error.

**Solution;**
Make sure to create the source/file first in the `_layouts` folder if you have created a block (content-type) in block library.